# Destroy Session on browser back

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, session

Is their any way to destroy the Session on browser back.
I'm using the Paypal payment method,during the payment process user redirected to the Paypal site for payment & if user click on the Paypal cancel button it redirects back to cart page, again if user click the browser back button it send back to the Paypal site for payment.
I tried the script and it successfully blocked the Back button in cart page,but without script is their any other way ?

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
history.pushState({ page: 1 }, "Title 1", "#no-back");
window.onhashchange = function (event) {
  window.location.hash = "no-back";
};
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you list down the browsers you checked.

Comment: In chrome and   Firefox too